Chemical Coin Flipping as Divination
Let me explain what the odd title means. In the I Ching, a book of ancient Chinese divination, there is a process of using 50 rods to produce what is essentially a binary outcome. The details aren't critical to understand the question, but roughly, the rods are divided into two groups by just grabbing a bunch at random, and then separating them out in groups of 4. The remainder you get from this process determines if the outcome is yin or yang, and this process is done 6 times to get a combination of yins and yangs that are looked up in a big table of fortune telling to know the outcome.
This is very cool and good, and I want to build on it for a setting I'm working on. But I'd like to dial up the ritual aspect a bit, while preserving the basic idea. The main issue I have is that when separating the rods, it feels like a skilled magician could easily by feel get a desired number of rods, and thus invalidate the divination. Modern diviners who consult the I Ching say that any random process can be used, like flipping coins, for example, but this does not feel magical to me. I could see characters doing something like this as a last resort when proper ritual components are not available.
I think something really cool would be if it were possible to prepare some kind of substance similar to gun powder to go into a burner which could burn two different colors, perhaps depending on the presence of some impurities. Then when the question to be divined is asked, it can be written on some scroll, treated with this substance, and can be burnt. The kind of fire that is produced can be used to determine the outcome of the divination. I think this is significantly more mystical feeling.
I want to know if this is actually possible. I like when my settings are grounded in enough realism that skepticism is possible. The world has enough magic in it that I certainly can just not explain it, but I think magic is most interesting when there's just a little bit of evidence each way, so I would be very interested to know if such a substance can be produced using only the materials available to a medieval Europe or Asia. I feel like it should be possible because I've seen fireworks in lots of colors, but I don't know enough about how they work to know if these are modern innovations.

(1) When trying to get an answer using I Ching, it is the querent, not the wise interpreter, who manipulates the yarrow stalks; this is sort of the entire point of the procedure. (2) Yes, if you have ever seen fireworks, then you know that pyrotechnic compositions can burn with various colors. But then when making pyrotechnic compositions the one thing you do not want is random impurities. The mixture is intended to the explosive; you definitely do not want it to behave in unpredictable ways.

Apologies for any inaccuracies, my goal was merely to impart the broad idea for those who do not know about the method.

You could always soak the slips of paper with some chemical that burns a particular colour. Drop those into a mystical hat and let the querent pick a slip of paper out of the hat. Luck or Fate would choose the colour.

Or make the querent pick one of two snuffboxes of mystical powder from a bag shaken by the seer.

Welcome to the World of Scientology (and it'll be interesting if this gets us all sued)
Skeptics and electrical engineers the world over have known that the basis of Scientology, the detection of Thetans, is done using e-meters — originally nothing more than a wheatstone bridge circuit.
My point in saying this? A wheatstone bridge is used to identify an unknown resistance... but what happens when you have a randomly variable resistance, like human skin on a nervous human? You get random measurements! Which the initiated interpreted to mean the presence (or lack thereof) of Thetans.
What you're after is the chemical version of an electronic wheatstone bridge
Getting colored smoke is trivial. But how to get randomly colored smoke?
Heh-heh...
What you need is INK! But not just any ink. You need ink suffused with the various chemicals. And not just in any way! You need the ink to be layered. Oils of varying viscosity are used to create physical layers in the ink well. Given a bit of time, the ink will will always separate back into these several layers. Each layer contains both emulsified ink and the chemical of a particular color smoke with increasing density as the layers descend into the inkwell so that the top layer isn't always the predominant color.
The random variability comes from the writer of the scroll, who will dip randomly as humans do. Call this a pseudo-religious medieval mouse-based CAPTCHA process. The fact that you'll have some of the other colors just proves the veracity of the process! Life is complicated! No answer is 100% certain!
Of course, a skilled initiate of the process becomes somewhat... adept... at securing a desired answer. You didn't think getting rid of all your Thetans was free, did you?

This seems like it has a good shot. The I Ching actually has not just 2 outcomes for a given "flip", but 4, and I suppressed this detail. The other two options are for when one of yin or yang wants to switch to the other. Most of the time, if you used the I Ching to do divination, you would get not one, but two answers, reflecting some cosmic changes in circumstance. It stands to reason that you could just shake the inkwell a bit to mix things a bit, and get anything from "mostly one color" to "pretty thoroughly mixed" and leave it to the diviner's first impressions as to how to interpret.
